# Remove all link in Google except homepage

Tags: seo

I have 180 pages indexed in Google and i need to remove all except root domaine.com/

What is the syntaxe in https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals ?
domaine.com/$ ?

My robots.txt

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /$
```

And meta robots

```
<?php
$robotIndex = "index,nofollow";
if(!empty($_GET)) {
        $robotIndex = "noindex,nofollow";
}
?>
<meta name="robots" content="<?=$robotIndex?>" />
```

Thanks you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Hello @JohnConde i dont speak good english sorry... Its not good tag ?

Comment: Are you able to do it manually, one by one?

Comment: i have 180 link :/ If i redirect this link in a error 404 its good for remove him ? Or its error 500 ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't block the files with a robots.txt if you are also adding a meta robots noindex to each page, since Google will obey the robots.txt command and therefore never get the meta robots noindex. Just the meta robots is enough, but it can take some time for Google to re-crawl all the site's pages, which has to happen before they can be removed from their index.

You can speed up the process by adding an XML sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools with all 180 URLs, after you add the meta robots tags. This will get them crawled faster.

If the 180 URLs are in a few separate directories, then you can use the Google Webmaster Tools URL Removal tool to delete individual directories from their index, not just pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Indexing API to delete urls.
Send batch requests.